# Use PL/SQL Function in JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

i need to call PL/SQL Function that return an Object Type in table form.
Basically like:

```
select * from TABLE(get_druck_variablen(123456);
```

in JOOQ im using native query so far and it works:

```
final Result<Record> result = create.fetch("select * from TABLE(myschema.get_druck_variablen(" + id + "))");
```

But i want to do it in JOOQ properly.

1) I've come to this:

```
final GetDruckVariablen getDruckVariablen = new GetDruckVariablen();
getDruckVariablen.setPId(id);
getDruckVariablen.execute();
```

but then i got this exception

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate de.company.jooq.routines.GetDruckVariablen.toString()
```

2) And then i've tried this:

```
  final TabOtDruckVariablenRecord getDruckVariablen = Routines.getDruckVariablen(create.configuration(), id).;
```

then i got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select "array_table"."COLUMN_VALUE" from table ("MYSCHEMA"."GET_DRUCK_VARIABLEN"(?)) "array_table"]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "array_table"."COLUMN_VALUE": ungültiger Bezeichner
```

For the info, here are my PL/SQL function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION      get_druck_variablen(p_id IN vk_types.t_id) RETURN myschema.tab_ot_druck_variablen 
PIPELINED 
IS 
....
BEGIN 
END get_druck_variablen;
```

The Object Types:

```
create or replace TYPE      ot_druck_variablen FORCE AS OBJECT 
( 
  ob_id   NUMBER(9, 0), 
  ob_txv_name VARCHAR2(100), 
  ob_txv_wert VARCHAR2(2000) 
)
```

The Table type:

```
create or replace TYPE      tab_ot_druck_variablen AS TABLE OF myschema.ot_druck_variablen
```

I'm really hoping that someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Ivan

---

Added Stake traces for the answer to:

```
    final GetDruckVariablen getDruckVariablen = new GetDruckVariablen();
    getDruckVariablen.setPId(id);
    getDruckVariablen.execute(dslContext.configuration());
```

Stack traces:

```
      2017-08-16 22:25:16.039 ERROR 4928 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed 

      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) 
            at de.mycompany.druckauftrag.DruckAuftragApplication.main(DruckAuftragApplication.java:31) 
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) 
      Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select "array_table"."COLUMN_VALUE" from table ("MYSCHEMA"."GET_DRUCK_VARIABLEN"(?)) "array_table"]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "array_table"."COLUMN_VALUE": ungültiger Bezeichner 

            at org.jooq_3.9.3.ORACLE.debug(Unknown Source) 
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231) 
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) 
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.translate(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:92) 
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.handle(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:81) 
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.exception(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:54) 
            at org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.exception(ExecuteListeners.java:245) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:364) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:315) 
            at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2708) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine.executeSelectFromOracle(AbstractRoutine.java:362) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine.execute(AbstractRoutine.java:318) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine.execute(AbstractRoutine.java:287) 
            at de.mycompany.druckauftrag.container.cask.KfzParam.getDruckVariablen(KfzParam.java:59) 
            at de.mycompany.druckauftrag.container.cask.KfzParam.befuelleVariablen(KfzParam.java:36) 
            at de.mycompany.druckauftrag.service.DokumentService.erzeugeDokument(DokumentService.java:55) 
            at de.mycompany.druckauftrag.service.XmlCreator.createXml(XmlCreator.java:33) 
            at de.mycompany.druckauftrag.DruckAuftragApplication.run(DruckAuftragApplication.java:46) 
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) 
            ... 11 common frames omitted 
      Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "array_table"."COLUMN_VALUE": ungültiger Bezeichner 

            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4901) 
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385) 
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source) 
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
            at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) 
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.execute(Unknown Source) 
            at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:195) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:270) 
            at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:349) 
            ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for your tips and answer. We are using JOOQ 3.9.3 .

Comment: @LukasEder apparently im still having the problem, did the newest JOOQ 3.9.5 solve this? To bad i can't check this. Our latest JOOQ Version in our nexus repository are 3.9.3. I have to wait untill it get added.

Comment: Not sure yet, I'm afraid. Would you mind posting the stack traces for both of your exceptions?

Comment: I just posted the stack traces. At least i didn't get an NullPointerException more. The booth stack traces to 1) and 2) approach are similar.

Comment: Hi @LukasEder, we have notice that JOOQ can't used Pipelined function. So we change the routine without the pipeline and it works.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this with 3.9 and 3.10 with no avail. The fact that `"COLUMN_VALUE"` is being fetched indicates that jOOQ "thinks" that the returned table type contains only one unnamed column, as in `CREATE TYPE tab_ot_druck_variablen AS TABLE OF NUMBER`. Are you sure: 1) you've regenerated the schema after you might have changed the type of that return table? 2) There are no alternative code generation artefacts on your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you've run into a bug (that was probably fixed by now). As soon as I know what jOOQ version you're using, I'll update my answer with a link to the relevant GitHub issue.

#### Regarding 1) and the `NullPointerException`

A possible reason for the NPE in your attempt 1):

```java
final GetDruckVariablen getDruckVariablen = new GetDruckVariablen();
getDruckVariablen.setPId(id);
getDruckVariablen.execute();
```

... might be the fact that you're not passing the `Configuration` to the `execute()` method. The `Configuration` less method assumes that your routine call has been previously "attached" to a `Configuration`. But better pass it explicitly:

```java
getDruckVariablen.execute(configuration);
```

#### A side-note on your native query usage:

You're surely aware of this, but I have to mention it for future readers. Your usage of the jOOQ plain SQL API exposes a certain risk of SQL injection, in addition to putting pressure on the cursor cache:

```java
final Result<Record> result = create.fetch(
  "select * from TABLE(myschema.get_druck_variablen(" + id + "))");
```

Better to use a bind variable, which is perfectly possible with plain SQL as well:

```java
final Result<Record> result = create.fetch(
  "select * from TABLE(myschema.get_druck_variablen(?))", id);
```